# Swing not antialiasing correctly

Tags: java, swing, graphics, fonts, jlabel

I have a frame with a very standard `JLabel`.

No matter how big the font, or how small/big the `JLabel`, the text is always sharp.

I'd like for it to be **antialiased**.

Looking up on so, I found a few questions but *no solutions*.

**Using this answer:**

[Anti-aliased JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869693/anti-aliased-jlabel)

I understood that it's useless to set the hints.

I have also tried to no avail:

```
String property = "swing.aatext";
if (null == System.getProperty(property))
System.setProperty(property, "true");
```

And here's the screenshot of the text, font [Comfortaa](http://www.dafont.com/it/comfortaa.font), size 90:

[image]

The same problem comes with all fonts and sizes I have tried so far.

Am I missing out on some way to enable the antialiasing?

I have not changed the `JLabel` in any way, added custom graphics, code, or anything at all. It's a black `JPanel` on a `JFrame`, with a `JLabel` in the middle.

**FAQ:**

- Java 8
- Run from Eclipse 4.1
- Window 10
- Both on 4k and FHD Screen
- [Nimbus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html)
- Both with [decorated and undecorated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated-boolean-) frames
- Both with black and [transparent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) background
- Font installed on windows, not [loaded as resource](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Loadfontfromttffile.htm)
- Same behaviour with any font
- I have used swing in the past, same machine, same version of everything, no issues that I can remember

**Am I doing something wrong? Any ideas?**

**MCVE:**   ---> The code is mine, I just changed the font because you might not have [Comfortaa](http://www.dafont.com/it/comfortaa.font) installed.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel mcveLabel;
    private JLabel mcveLabel2;

    public TestFrame() {

        setSize(374, 153);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        mcveLabel = new JLabel("Antialias");
        mcveLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 60));
        mcveLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        mcveLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.add(mcveLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mcveLabel2 = new JLabel("NEEDED");
        mcveLabel2.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        mcveLabel2.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        mcveLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panel.add(mcveLabel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new TestFrame();

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Added screen with the same font as the MCVE.
[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything, it exits right away. I assume when you really run the code, you have a `setVisible(true)` call on the TestFrame object somewhere? Please post the real code.

Comment: @Ervin Bolwidt Oops, sorry, taking out the useless bits I accidentally deleted setVisible. Added now.

Comment: I assume you have searched for posts ? It's nicely antialiases on my MacBook, can't help you much. It seems to be quite dependent on the Look & Feel that you are using with Swing, and perhaps on the platform.

Comment: I'm using the default look and feel, Nimbus. Other than that, I haven't changed anything. All my platform info are in the question. No idea what could be causing this? I have searched all over but no one has an answer.

Comment: @LoryA May you consider to test it on another screen? I've tested you code and text diplayed is antialiased (Debian)

Comment: @Trasher I have tested it on both a 4k high dpi, 4k low dpi, fhd displays, no difference. Same laptop though, I don't have another. At this point, what can be wrong with the laptop that is causing this?